# Can I install Adobe Reader X and still keep Reader 9 also?

Tags: adobe-reader

I'd like to install Adobe Reader X but for various reasons I'm not quite ready to get rid of Reader 9 yet. Is it possible to install Reader X but avoid the automatic removal of Reader 9 in the process?

Comment: My first thought (it wasn't very helpful) was why do you want either of the horrible bits of bloatware.

Comment: It might help to know the various reasons.

Comment: Adobe Reader X is less vulnerable to various PDF exploits due to the code sandboxing and other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Some users find it helpful to mix and match the features and workflows from different versions of Adobe Acrobat to achieve familiar results with their documents. However, as a best practice, only one version of Adobe Acrobat should be installed on a single computer. The presence of two or more versions of the same program on one machine consistently leads to disabled functionality, printer conflicts, and PDF display errors in web browsers, among other problems. Nevertheless, for users willing to accept the risks, installation of multiple Acrobat versions is relatively simple.

Read more  about it on: [How to Install Multiple Instances of Adobe Acrobat](http://www.ehow.com/how_5904190_install-multiple-instances-adobe-acrobat.html#ixzz1VVL0uVN7)

Comment: That looks like it's about the standard version rather than the reader, I couldn't find anything except horror stories for multiple versions of the reader that were newer than version 7.

Comment: Well ok let me explain you in easy terms

Comment: I think there are some known issues, i also tried but there was conflict even i tried installing it on different drives.Let me find a working solution my self and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine, like Oracle Virtualbox. have a shared folder.

I have a 32bit virtual machine for using my old scanners and devices that only work on 32bit/16bit windows.  You'll have to have virtualization turned on in your bios, and your windows license key will likely work for an install on the inside computer.

You can disable a lot of things on the virtual machine's copy of windows, like uninstall all kinds of apps and services then it loads very quickly and with a shared folder, it is easy to move items back and forth.